# Anaconda Navigator Not Opening (W10-64bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I've tried everything and I still can not deal with this.

`conda update conda`

`conda update anaconda`

`conda update anaconda-navigator`

`conda update --all`

`pip install pyqt5` (I took this from [#1581](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1581) )

`conda install qt --force` (idea from [#9158](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9158) )

`conda install pyqt --force` (idea from [#9158](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9158) )

I've also uninstalled everything and reinstalled, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

#### Here are some details:

**`conda info`**:

```
active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\sebal\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.5.9
    conda-build version : 3.12.1
         python version : 3.6.6.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\sebal\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\sebal\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\sebal\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.9 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.6.6 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

**`conda list --show-channel-urls`**

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py36_0    defaults
alabaster                 0.7.11                   py36_0    defaults
anaconda                  custom           py36h363777c_0    defaults
anaconda-client           1.7.1                    py36_0    defaults
anaconda-navigator        1.8.7                    py36_0    defaults
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py36_0    defaults
appdirs                   1.4.3            py36h28b3542_0    defaults
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0    defaults
astroid                   2.0.4                    py36_0    defaults
astropy                   3.0.4            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
atomicwrites              1.1.5                    py36_0    defaults
attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0    defaults
automat                   0.7.0                    py36_0    defaults
babel                     2.6.0                    py36_0    defaults
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0    defaults
backports                 1.0                      py36_1    defaults
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py36_2    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py36_0    defaults
bitarray                  0.8.3            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h7e685f7_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
blaze                     0.11.3                   py36_0    defaults
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0    defaults
blosc                     1.14.3               he51fdeb_0    defaults
bokeh                     0.13.0                   py36_0    defaults
boto                      2.49.0                   py36_0    defaults
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36h452e1ab_1    defaults
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5    defaults
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0    defaults
certifi                   2018.8.13                py36_0    defaults
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h945400d_0    defaults
chardet                   3.0.4                    py36_1    defaults
click                     6.7              py36hec8c647_0    defaults
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0    defaults
clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_1    defaults
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0    defaults
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py36_0    defaults
conda                     4.5.9                    py36_0    defaults
conda-build               3.12.1                   py36_0    defaults
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    defaults
conda-verify              3.1.0                    py36_0    defaults
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3    defaults
constantly                15.1.0           py36h28b3542_0    defaults
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36he5d52c0_0    defaults
cryptography              2.3              py36h74b6da3_0    defaults
cryptography-vectors      2.3                      py36_0    defaults
curl                      7.61.0               h7602738_0    defaults
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0    defaults
cython                    0.28.5           py36h6538335_0    defaults
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
dask                      0.18.2                   py36_0    defaults
dask-core                 0.18.2                   py36_0    defaults
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_1    defaults
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
distributed               1.22.1                   py36_0    defaults
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py36_2    defaults
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h3d2d736_0    defaults
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36hfa6e2cd_2    defaults
filelock                  3.0.4                    py36_0    defaults
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1    defaults
flask-cors                3.0.6                    py36_0    defaults
freetype                  2.9.1                ha9979f8_1    defaults
future                    0.16.0                   py36_1    defaults
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0    defaults
gevent                    1.3.5            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
glob2                     0.6                      py36_0    defaults
greenlet                  0.4.14           py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
h5py                      2.8.0            py36h3bdd7fb_1    defaults
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1    defaults
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2    defaults
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0    defaults
hyperlink                 18.0.0                   py36_0    defaults
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0    defaults
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1    defaults
idna                      2.7                      py36_0    defaults
imageio                   2.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0    defaults
incremental               17.5.0                   py36_0    defaults
intel-openmp              2018.0.3                      0    defaults
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0    defaults
ipython                   6.5.0                    py36_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0    defaults
ipywidgets                7.4.0                    py36_0    defaults
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0    defaults
itsdangerous              0.24                     py36_1    defaults
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0    defaults
jedi                      0.12.1                   py36_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.10                     py36_0    defaults
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2    defaults
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_5    defaults
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0    defaults
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py36_1    defaults
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0    defaults
jupyterlab                0.33.8                   py36_0    defaults
jupyterlab_launcher       0.11.2                   py36_0    defaults
keyring                   13.2.1                   py36_0    defaults
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h6538335_0    defaults
launcher                  1.0.0                         4    defaults
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hfa6e2cd_2    defaults
libcurl                   7.61.0               h7602738_0    defaults
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7    defaults
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0    defaults
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4    defaults
libtiff                   4.0.9                hb8ad9f9_1    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1    defaults
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0    defaults
llvmlite                  0.24.0           py36h6538335_0    defaults
locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1    defaults
lxml                      4.2.4            py36hef2cd61_0    defaults
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    defaults
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    defaults
markupsafe                1.0              py36hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
matplotlib                2.2.2            py36had4c4a9_2    defaults
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1    defaults
menuinst                  1.4.14           py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
mistune                   0.8.3            py36hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1    defaults
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36hb217b18_4    defaults
mkl_fft                   1.0.4            py36h1e22a9b_1    defaults
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h77b88f5_1    defaults
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
mpmath                    1.0.0                    py36_2    defaults
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36he980bc4_1    defaults
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    defaults
multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py36_0    defaults
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.3.1                    py36_0    defaults
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0    defaults
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0    defaults
nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
node-webkit               0.10.1                        0    defaults
nose                      1.3.7                    py36_2    defaults
notebook                  5.6.0                    py36_0    defaults
numba                     0.39.0           py36h830ac7b_0    defaults
numexpr                   2.6.7            py36hf2b2a6d_0    defaults
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h9fa60d3_0    defaults
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h4a99626_0    defaults
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0    defaults
odo                       0.5.1            py36h7560279_0    defaults
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0    defaults
openpyxl                  2.5.5                    py36_0    defaults
openssl                   1.0.2o               hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0    defaults
pandas                    0.23.4           py36h830ac7b_0    defaults
pandoc                    2.2.1                h1a437c5_0    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1    defaults
parso                     0.3.1                    py36_0    defaults
partd                     0.3.8            py36hc8e763b_0    defaults
path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_0    defaults
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0    defaults
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0    defaults
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0    defaults
pillow                    5.2.0            py36h08bbbbd_0    defaults
pip                       18.0                      <pip>
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0    defaults
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1    defaults
pluggy                    0.7.1                    py36_0    defaults
ply                       3.11                     py36_0    defaults
prometheus_client         0.3.1                    py36_0    defaults
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0    defaults
psutil                    5.4.6            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
py                        1.5.4                    py36_0    defaults
pyasn1                    0.4.4                    py36_0    defaults
pyasn1-modules            0.2.2                    py36_0    defaults
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.18                     py36_1    defaults
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36hfa6e2cd_9    defaults
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py36h74b6da3_0    defaults
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py36_0    defaults
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0    defaults
PyHamcrest                1.9.0                     <pip>
pylint                    2.1.1                    py36_0    defaults
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36h6538335_0    defaults
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py36_1    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36ha878b3d_0    defaults
PyQt5                     5.11.2                    <pip>
PyQt5_sip                 4.19.12                   <pip>
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0    defaults
pytables                  3.4.4            py36he6f6034_0    defaults
pytest                    3.7.1                    py36_0    defaults
pytest-arraydiff          0.2              py36h39e3cac_0    defaults
pytest-astropy            0.4.0                    py36_0    defaults
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0    defaults
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
pytest-remotedata         0.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
python                    3.6.6                hea74fb7_0    defaults
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0    defaults
pytz                      2018.5                   py36_0    defaults
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36h452e1ab_2    defaults
pywin32                   223              py36hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
pywinpty                  0.5.4                    py36_0    defaults
pyyaml                    3.13             py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
pyzmq                     17.1.0           py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
qt                        5.9.6            vc14h62aca36_0    defaults
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0    defaults
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0    defaults
qtpy                      1.4.2                    py36_1    defaults
requests                  2.19.1                   py36_0    defaults
rope                      0.11.0                   py36_0    defaults
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
scikit-image              0.14.0           py36h6538335_1    defaults
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hae9bb9f_0    defaults
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0    defaults
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py36_0    defaults
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0    defaults
service_identity          17.0.0           py36h28b3542_0    defaults
setuptools                40.0.0                   py36_0    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2    defaults
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h17d0c80_0    defaults
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0    defaults
six                       1.11.0                   py36_1    defaults
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3    defaults
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0    defaults
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py36_0    defaults
sortedcontainers          2.0.4                    py36_0    defaults
sphinx                    1.7.6                    py36_0    defaults
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py36_1    defaults
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py36_1    defaults
spyder                    3.3.0                    py36_0    defaults
spyder-kernels            0.2.4                    py36_0    defaults
sqlalchemy                1.2.10           py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.24.0               h7602738_0    defaults
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h452e1ab_0    defaults
sympy                     1.2                      py36_0    defaults
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h30f5020_0    defaults
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1    defaults
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0    defaults
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3    defaults
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0    defaults
tornado                   5.1              py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0    defaults
twisted                   18.7.0           py36hfa6e2cd_1    defaults
typed-ast                 1.1.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0    defaults
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0    defaults
urllib3                   1.23                     py36_0    defaults
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_3    defaults
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    defaults
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0    defaults
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1    defaults
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0    defaults
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0    defaults
widgetsnbextension        3.4.0                    py36_0    defaults
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py36_1    defaults
win_unicode_console       0.5              py36hcdbd4b5_0    defaults
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0    defaults
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    defaults
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36hfa6e2cd_2    defaults
xlrd                      1.1.0                    py36_1    defaults
xlsxwriter                1.0.5                    py36_0    defaults
xlwings                   0.11.8                   py36_0    defaults
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0    defaults
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2    defaults
zeromq                    4.2.5                he025d50_1    defaults
zict                      0.1.3                    py36_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2    defaults
zope                      1.0                      py36_0    defaults
zope.interface            4.5.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
```

When I run **`anaconda-navigator`** from the Prompt, I receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 169, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Then I tried **`conda install pyside`** :

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf
  - pyside
  - python=3
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure that there is no spaces in your path.

You can also try installing the anaconda navigator as below:

**conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator**

Comment: thanks for your answer. I run the Prompt as administrator and the default path is: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`
so I think there's no problem with spaces.

I use **conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator** to install anaconda navigator but unfortunately I get the same result when I want to open the software

Answer (score 0):

After updating or trough fresh install anaconda-navigator stops running trough .lnk
`C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3 C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py`

`conda install anaconda=2022.05`
break up

`anaconda-navigator 2.2.0-py39haa95532_0 --> 2.1.4-py39haa95532_0`
still broken

`anaconda-navigator 2.1.4-py39haa95532_0 --> 2.1.2-py39haa95532_0`
still broken

`anaconda-navigator 2.1.2-py39haa95532_0 --> 2.1.1-py39_0`
works and offer update to 2.2.0 and after update trough GUI break up again

**But is runable trough cmd promt** `anaconda-navigator`